# change variable name in foreach with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Is there any chance to change PHP variable with jquery?

My code

```js
$(function() {
  $('#websites').hide();
  $('#main-cat').change(function() {
    if ($('#main-cat').val() == 'websites') {
      $('#websites').show();
      var echo = "<?php echo $ws->websites;?>";
    } else {
      $('#row_dim').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="websites">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Izvēlieties apakškategoriju</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="select-general form-control" name="category">
      <option label="---Izvēlēties---"></option>
      <?php foreach ($websites as $ws){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo **$ws->websites**;?>">
        <?php echo $ws->websites;?>
      </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

But i want to change `$ws->websites` to `$ws->applications` dynamically depending on main category choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.echo the code depend on js condition

```
var echo="";
if($('#main-cat').val() == 'websites') {
        echo = "<?php echo $ws->websites;?>"; 
     } else {
        echo = "<?php echo $ws->application;?>"; 
     }
```